# how do i display information from 3 tables into 1 table with php. i'm using mysql workbench

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

this is my code

```
<?php
    $tilkobling = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","oppgave_normalisering");
    $sql = "SELECT person_table.personr, person_table.navn, person_table.adresse, person_table.mobilnr, person_table.postnr, person_table.bilde, mobil_table.model, sted_table.sted FROM mobil_table, person_table, sted_table";
    $datasett = $tilkobling->query($sql)
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>

<table >
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><b>Nr<b></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><b>Navn<b></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><b>Adresse<b></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><b>Postnr</b></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><b>Sted</b></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><b>Mobilnr</b></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><b>Modell</b></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><b>Bilde</b></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php while ($rad = mysqli_fetch_array($datasett)) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $rad["personr"]; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $rad["navn"]; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $rad["adresse"]; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $rad["postnr"]; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $rad["sted"]; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $rad["mobilnr"]; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $rad["model"]; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $rad["bilde"]; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </table>

</body>
</html>
```

this is the result in google chrome.

[image]

This is what my tables look like in mysql workbench

as you can see under the Nr colum the numbers replicate themselves. i want it to only show 1, 2, 3 and not the replicated colums.

Comment: Don't forget the `WHERE`

Comment: And maybe `JOIN`

Comment: You're creating a full cross product between the tables. You need to use joining conditions to relate the tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific value that you`re looking for, you should be using `WHERE`, otherwise you can use `SELECT DISTINCT` at the beginning of your statement

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help!

The problem was solved with using "WHERE" + "AND". As you can see in the code i wrote

`WHERE person_table.personr = sted_table.stednr AND person_table.personr = mobil_table.modelnr"`

which were the colums that were interfering with eachother. This 
solved the problem where the information was duplicating for each value in the Mobil_table.

End php code <

```
$sql = "SELECT person_table.personr, person_table.navn, person_table.adresse, person_table.mobilnr, person_table.postnr, person_table.bilde, mobil_table.model, sted_table.sted FROM mobil_table, person_table, sted_table WHERE person_table.personr = sted_table.stednr AND person_table.personr = mobil_table.modelnr";
```